# Syntax error in while loop BASH

Tags: bash, background, while-loop, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a loop that will run matlab command in the background the following way:

```
while [$i -lt $p] || [$i -eq $p] do
     $i>i.txt
     echo "matlab -nojvm -r readtxt_abc;pause(1);myfunc1(a,b,c);clear" |sh &
     let i=i+1
done
```

and I get an error of

```
bash:syntax error near unexpected token 'done'
```

if anyone have any idea what is the reason for the error pls let me know, thank u!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square brackets require spaces around them since they are, in essence, commands instead of syntax elements. You also need a semicolon when you put `do` on the same line as `while`.

```
while [ $i -lt $p ] || [ $i -eq $p ]; do
```

The less-than-or-equal operator is `-le` instead of doing two tests.

However, this is preferred in Bash:

```
while ((i <= p)); do
     # $i>i.txt     # this line doesn't make any sense
     matlab -nojvm -r 'readtxt_abc;pause(1);myfunc1(a,b,c);clear' &    # there's no need to pipe this to sh
     ((i++))
done
```

But you can let Bash maintain your counter variable:

```
for ((i = 0; i <= p; i++)); do
    . . .
done
```

Perhaps the second line should be:

```
echo "$i" > "$i.txt"
```

but I don't know why you'd want to do that.

Comment: the i.txt line relates to something, just ignore it. about your comment regarding the background, whenever I do it the way you mention it is suspended and not running. got some progress, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
while [ $i -lt $p ] || [ $i -eq $p ]; do
 $i>i.txt
 echo "matlab -nojvm -r readtxt_abc;pause(1);myfunc1(a,b,c);clear" |sh &
 let i=i+1
done
```

Remember that `[` and `]` have to be surrounded by "space"

Comment: Now it doesn't again: "-bash: syntax error in conditional expression
/-bash: syntax error near ']'". The brackets (`[` or `[[`) aren't syntax elements, they're commands.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson thank you for remind me that. At first I didn't remember

Answer (score -2):

I believe you are missing some **;** try:

```
while [$i -lt $p] || [$i -eq $p]; do
 $i>i.txt;
 echo "matlab -nojvm -r readtxt_abc;pause(1);myfunc1(a,b,c);clear" |sh &;
 let i=i+1;
done
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it Identifies the ';' automatically, I tried to put it the way u told me line by line and I got the error just after the matlab command, not the end of the loop, any ideas?